# Learning about Intents, passing Data

Tags: android

Does anyone know any good resources where a beginner and understand Intents and Contexts. I understand the basics of activities, but i don't really understand how Intents go along with this.

Also, anyone know any good resources to learn about passing information between activities? For example, I have a splash screen, and I have multiple levels for an addition activity. I created an addition activity, but i want to be able to press different buttons to determine different difficulties. So obviously I dont want to create like 5 different layouts with the same activity with just the difficulty changed. So since I already have the code for the addition activity, how can I pass data from the splash activity to the addition activity? The data might be an int that designates a difficulty level. I would then be able to access the int from the addition activity and base it off of that.

Thanks

Comment: Read this http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily pass Int between activities using Intents.

**Activity1**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("param", 1);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Activity2**

```
onCreate(Bundle b) {
    int param =  getIntent().getIntExtra("param");
}
```

All primary datatypes Integer,Long,String,etc can be passed as an extra. Technically, anything that is `Serializable` can be an extra.

Eg.

```
class Student implements Serializable
{
//...
}

Intent intent = //...
intent.putSerializable("key", new Student());
```

To retrieve it,

```
Student s = (Student)getIntent().getSerializableExtra();
```

Comment: Ahh that makes a lot of sense. So what we are basically doing is sending a piece of data (string, int, etc) that we can retrieve later. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

I really recommend a lot of Vogella's tutorials. They've really helped me out a lot.

Comment: Developer.android.com is one of the best play-script for android beginners